# Expand data frame with a split in R

Tags: r, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“unpacking” a factor list from a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226575/unpacking-a-factor-list-from-a-data-frame)

If I have a data frame which has the same format as something like this

```
X   geneA,geneB
Y   geneD,geneF
Z   geneH,geneL,geneS
```

I am trying to find a quick and effiecent way of expanding it so that I can split (by a comma) the second column and assign the corresponding value of the first column to give me something like this

```
X   geneA
X   geneB
Y   geneD
Y   geneF
Z   geneH
Z   geneL
Z   geneS
```

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `melt.list` from the package `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)

dat = read.table(header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                 text="X   geneA,geneB
                       Y   geneD,geneF
                       Z   geneH,geneL,geneS")

lst = strsplit(dat$V2, ",")
names(lst) = dat$V1

res = melt(lst)

res
#   value L1
# 1 geneA  X
# 2 geneB  X
# 3 geneD  Y
# 4 geneF  Y
# 5 geneH  Z
# 6 geneL  Z
# 7 geneS  Z
```