# expanding R data.table by splitting on one column

Tags: r, data.table

I have an R `data.table` like this:

```
> old_table
     id  values
  1:  1   A,B,C
  2:  2     D,E
  3:  3       F
  4:  4 G,H,I,J
```

I want to expand the table by splitting up the values column by commas (,) like so:

```
> new_table
     id value
  1:  1     A
  2:  1     B
  3:  1     C
  4:  2     D
  5:  2     E
  6:  3     F
  7:  4     G
  7:  4     H
  7:  4     I
  7:  4     J
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226575/unpacking-a-factor-list-from-a-data-frame

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
new_table <- old_table[, .(value=strsplit(values, ',')[[1]]), id]
```

Gives what you're after.  Although there's a chance I'm wrong based on what the actual data type is of "values" in `old_table`.  Here's how I set it up

```
old_table <- data.table(id=1:4,
                        values=c('A,B,C',
                                 'D,E',
                                 'F',
                                 'G,H,I,J'))

new_table <- old_table[, .(value=strsplit(values, ',')[[1]]), id]
```

This outputs

```
    id value
 1:  1     A
 2:  1     B
 3:  1     C
 4:  2     D
 5:  2     E
 6:  3     F
 7:  4     G
 8:  4     H
 9:  4     I
10:  4     J
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it using `tidyverse` tools `separate` and `gather`. You need to check what the longest comma-separated group you have in your `values` column is though, and leave enough variable names in the `into` argument for `separate`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

old_table <- tibble(
  id = as.integer(c(1, 2, 3, 4)),
  values = c("A,B,C", "D,E", "F", "G,H,I,J")
)

max_commas <- max(str_count(old_table$values, ","))
old_table %>%
  separate(values, into = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"),  sep = ",") %>%
  gather(key = "key", value = "value", starts_with("v"), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  arrange(value)
#> Warning: Too few values at 3 locations: 1, 2, 3
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>       id value
#>    <int> <chr>
#>  1     1 A    
#>  2     1 B    
#>  3     1 C    
#>  4     2 D    
#>  5     2 E    
#>  6     3 F    
#>  7     4 G    
#>  8     4 H    
#>  9     4 I    
#> 10     4 J
```